# Why did my sprayed-on paint job look like it was rolled on?

Tags: paint, paint-clearcoat

I repainted a back portion of my car after hitting something and it turned out pretty good, however the paint has a strange texture. It feels smooth, but it looks similar to a rolled on paint job.

It looks similar to this, but it isn't as severe and I cannot get it on camera:

[image]

The paint glossiness looks great, but it almost looks like the paint underneath has this texture. It was wet sanded before spraying gloss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't provided the most accurate description of the paint, but I'm guessing you have what is known as [Orange Peel](https://www.drbeasleys.com/blog/2012/09/06/whats-the-deal-with-orange-peel/).

[image: Orange Peel Paint]

> The orange peel effect is caused by premature evaporation of thinner,
>   incorrect spray gun setup (ie. low air pressure or incorrect nozzle),
>   spraying at an angle other than perpendicularly, or applying excessive
>   paint.

No matter how smooth the paint may have been applied, the texture forms as the paint is curing.  You haven't explained if this issue is in the base color coat or in the clear coat finish.  This can sometimes be fixed via polishing, but often requires that the area be repainted..

And by the way... don't discount a rolled on paint job.  Here's the link to [the $50 paint job](http://www.rickwrench.com/50dollarpaint.html), where the guy paints the car with solid enamel color in his driveway using just a paint roller.  No spray guns involved.  No safety mask, no paint booth.  Easy, reliable, relatively safe, durable.

Comment: You should also let the OP know orange peel can be fixed in most cases by wet sanding, cutting, and polishing. It should also be of note, a lot of paint jobs end up with orange peel, which subsequently needs a little elbow grease to get fixed.

Comment: there was some wet sanding (up to 2000 grit) and buffing. I guess I will try buffing it more. Thank you.